# How to exit loop with ENTER

Tags: java, arrays, do-while

How do I exit this loop when user presses ENTER. This is part of the codes I have done. I am having problems in how to code when user presses ENTER.

```
static String[] itemList = new String[10];

do {
    System.out.print("Enter item (press ENTER to exit) " + (count + 1) + ":  ");
    String item = input.next();
    itemList[count] = item;
    if (item == "")
        count = itemList.length;
```

Comment: Where is the `while` in your code?

Comment: @LutzHorn this is only part of my coding.

Comment: @kumar can you please explain? sorry I just started learning programming & this is for my project

Comment: Not sure but can try Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\n"); do{ String data = scan.next();
    Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
    boolean b = m.matches();
    if(b)
     break;
    }// can try something similar to this

Comment: I have added the code below check in the answers section.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing `String`s using `==` not `.equals()`.

This compares the pointer to the `String`, not the contents of the `String`.

Comment: He means you have to use `String#equals` to compare strings, not `==`: `item.equals("")`. `==` compares references, not content. Please read some Java tutorial about strings.

Comment: @m0skit0 sorry i still don't quite understand. i just started learning programming for my course

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String readString = scanner.nextLine();
while(readString!=null)
{
    System.out.println(readString);
    if(readString.equals(""))
        System.out.println("Read Enter Key.");
    if(scanner.hasNextLine())
        readString = scanner.nextLine();
    else
        readString = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition before entering into loop. For example:

```
boolean statusIsNotReady = true;
while(statusIsNotReady) {
    // do your fty;
    if(someCondition) {
        statusIsNotReady = false; // If the status changed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SampleInputReader{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    String[] itemList = new String[10];
            int count = 0;
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            String data = "";

            do{
                    System.out.print("Enter item (press ENTER to exit) " + (count + 1)+ ":  ");
                    data = keyboard.nextLine();
                    if(data.isEmpty())
                        break;

                      itemList[count] = data;
                      count++;
            }while(true); 

            for(int i = 0; i< itemList.length; i++)
                System.out.println(itemList[i]);

}
}
```

But instead of Array i suggest you to use Arraylist.